# Customizing the boot message?

Tags: 12.04, boot, customization

When booting Ubuntu, I get this message:

[image]

Is it possible to change the text `Ubuntu 12.04` to `Loading, please wait.` ?

Comment: It's that link about plymouth?  The image I am showing is a text based loader.

Comment: Text based theme is still plymouth theme.

Comment: I see, so I have to change the whole theme?  I can't simply change the  text in the existing theme by opening up a text file in some configuration section or something like that?

Comment: I think so. Themes has to run early on boot so they can't rely on config files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can change the text without installing new themes:

```
sudo nano /etc/alternatives/text.plymouth
```

Then you can change the title within that file to anything you want.

[image]